Guy makes girl smokes crack, then she gets decapitated
I can't think of it for the life of me, but it's driving me crazy.... I think it was an early 90s movie and the bad guy makes this female smoke Ice or crack, then decapitates her and the cops show up later and say by the look in her eyes it looks like she would have been dead in minutes.....   It's been in my head all day and driving me nuts what movie it is.

Sounds like Showdown in Little Tokyo from 1991 with Dolph Lundgren and Brandon Lee where the villain does this to a girl called Angel:

Yoshida questions Angel about her loyalty, and she attempts to appease Yoshida by offering her body to him. Yoshida then drugs Angel and strips off her clothes, and then fondles her from behind before beheading her.
When the coroner runs an analysis on Angel's body, it is revealed that she had a large amount of methamphetamines in her system (induced by Yoshida) which would have led to her death anyway. 

They know this because her eyes are still dilated. Here's the trailer:




That was it!   Thank you so much! Been bothering me all day!
